# How to import npm semver on an ionic project with angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Angualr project with Ionic framework, I need to use Semvar to compare the local version with the API version to force users to update

after installing semver

```
npm install semver
```

I want to import it in the project and the `require` function is not compatible with angular

```
const semver = require('semver') ===> error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after

```
npm install semver
```

then it will be possible to import it by :

```
import * as semver from "semver";

semver.valid("1.2.3"); // "1.2.3"
semver.valid("a.b.c"); // null
semver.clean("  =v1.2.3   "); // "1.2.3"
semver.satisfies("1.2.3", "1.x || >=2.5.0 || 5.0.0 - 7.2.3"); // true
semver.gt("1.2.3", "9.8.7"); // false
semver.lt("1.2.3", "9.8.7"); // true
semver.minVersion(">=1.0.0"); // "1.0.0"
semver.valid(semver.coerce("v2")); // "2.0.0"
semver.valid(semver.coerce("42.6.7.9.3-alpha")); // "42.6.7"
```

[Source](https://deno.land/x/semver@v1.0.0)